# Merge two RDDs in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have two RDDs.

rdd1 = (String, String)

```
key1, value11
key2, value12
key3, value13
```

rdd2 = (String, String)

```
key2, value22
key3, value23
key4, value24
```

I need to form another RDD with merged rows from rdd1 and rdd2, the output should look like:

```
key2, value12 ; value22
key3, value13 ; value23
```

So, basically it's nothing but taking the intersection of the keys of rdd1 and rdd2 and then join their values.
** The values should be in order i.e. value(rdd1) + value(rdd2) and not reverse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this may be what you are looking for:

```
join(otherDataset, [numTasks])
```

When called on datasets of type (K, V) and (K, W), returns a dataset of (K, (V, W)) pairs with all pairs of elements for each key. Outer joins are supported through leftOuterJoin, rightOuterJoin, and fullOuterJoin.

[See the associated section of the docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#transformations)

Comment: I think (rdd1 join rdd2) works, and then map can be used to get the data in right format. Thanks

Comment: Just tested this on the Databricks community edition, on a spark 2.0.2-db cluster running scala 2.11. `(sc.parallelize(List((1, "a"), (2, "b"), (3, "c"))) join sc.parallelize(List((1, "z"), (2, "x"), (3, "y")))).collect().foreach(println)` produces a 3 item rdd with the expected tuples.

Answer (score 1):

Check `join()` in PairRDDFunctions:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions

Comment: A merge may not mean a JOIN imho